# slideToggle в разных div'aх

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть четыре квадрата (`div`), при нажатии на любой, отрабатывает `slideToggle()`.
Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на любой другой квадрат, прошлый сначала сворачивался, а лишь потом, на нажатом отрабатывал `slideToggle()`?

Comment: Задача, как описали её вы, просто бессмысленная. Если элементы изначально видны и клик происходит на каком-либо из них, то данный элемент свернётся. После клика на следующем элементе, сворачивать предыдущий не имеет смысла, т.к. он уже свёрнут. И так со всеми последующими элементами. Если же элементы изначально не видны, то кликнуть по ним, как вы понимаете, никак не получится. Поэтому уточняйте вопрос, показывайте html-код, относящийся к вопросу, и тогда можно будет что-то решать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант подойдет?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').bind('click', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if ($('div:not(:visible)').length) {
      $('div:not(:visible)').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(el).slideToggle('slow');
      });
    } else {
      $(el).slideToggle('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Прицнип такой:

- если есть закрытый `div`, то сначала его открываем, а на его `callback` закрываем `div`
- если закрытого `div` нет - просто открываем нажатый